# LINQ syntax and the where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have written some LINQ but it doesn't return the correct data, it seems to ignore my where clause.  Can anybody advise me on what I am doing wrong with the syntax?

```
IEnumerable<Ranking> lst = (from r in results
    join m in membersToRank on r.UserId equals m.userId
    join t in teamsToRank on m.teamId equals t.teamId
    where r.ResultDate >= rankingStart
        && r.ResultDate <= rankingEnd 
    select new Ranking
    {
        memberId = m.memberId,
        chain = t.chain,
        name = m.name,
        teamId = m.teamId,
        value = results.Count(i => i.IsCorrect && i.UserId == m.userId)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: you syntax is fine can you show what is going wrong means output of ur query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
value = results.Count(i => i.IsCorrect && i.UserId == m.userId)
```

will bypass the `where` clause. You have have to repeat the `where` there

```
value = results.Where(...).Count(i => i.IsCorrect && i.UserId == m.userId)
```

or

```
var results2 = results.Where(...)
```

and then use only `results2`.

(as a sidenote, it will even bypass the `join`, so it could become a little more complex depending on what you want)

Comment: Or instead of specifying the `where` and `join` clauses again, you could simply use the [`into`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045) keyword to create an identifier that refers to the already filtered and joined data.